# Contour plots using functions in R

Tags: r, function, contour

In the following code I'm trying to use the function norm.dem to generate a contour plot of the points given by x and y.  I can't seems to figure out how to do this.  I've tried everything I could think of.  For some reason the function isn't letting me put in values of sequence.  Shouldn't the outer function give me a list of values?

```
x=seq(-10,10,length=1000)
y=seq(-10,10,length=1000)

sigma <- matrix(c(10,-5,-5,20), ncol=2)
sigma

norm.den=function(x,y,sigma,mu) 
{
  j<-c(x,y)
  k=j-mu
  t<-t(k)
  s<-solve(sigma)
  d<-det(sigma)

  ((2.718)^(-t%*%s%*%k/2))/(2*(3.14)*sqrt(d))

}

z=outer(x,y,norm.den,sigma=sigma,mu=c(0,0))
```

Comment: You have the makings of a raster, if you plug that into [contour](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/contour) you should get what you are after. You may need to use `rasterFromXYZ()`

Good luck!

Comment: When I run the code as it is, it gives me the error 'Error in -t %*% s : non-conformable arguments.'

Comment: @HoneyDippedBadger um… the third parameter to `outer` is just the function name and the remainder of the `…` parameters in the call get passed to the function.

Comment: @HoneyDippedBadger This is not the problem here. The function is correctly called as all the arguments are provided in `outer`. In `norm.den`, `-t` is of dimension `1 2000` and `s` is of dimension `2 2`.

Comment: My mistake I'll pull that! Sorry for the mislead!

Comment: @Pascal I need to be able to build contour graphs using that specific s.  Is there a way for me to do that?

Comment: `exp` is a function in **R**, and much preferred (due to precision and readability) than `2.718^(...)`

Comment: @pretzelman check the dimensions of `t` (bad name for a variable btw) & `s`. that'll give you some idea of the error being generated

Comment: @hrbrmstr I understand what the error is.  The matrix dimensions do no match up so the multiplication isn't possible.  I need to know how to fix that.  I'm trying to feed single variables in one at a time and then have the function spit out x, y values to be plotted on a contour.

Answer (score 0):

Forcibly using `for()` loops works.

```
normden <- function(x, y, solvsig=ss, detsig=ds, mu=c(0, 0)) {
  k <- c(x, y) - mu
  tk <- t(k)
  (exp(-tk %*% ss %*% k / 2)) / (2*pi*sqrt(ds))
}

sigma <- matrix(c(10, -5, -5, 20), ncol=2)
ss <- solve(sigma)
ds <- det(sigma)

x <- seq(-10, 10, length=10)
y <- seq(-10, 10, length=10)
z <- array(dim=c(length(x), length(x)))
for(i in seq(x)) {
for(j in seq(y)) {
  z[i, j] <- normden(x=x[i], y=y[j])
}}
z
```

I couldn't get `outer()` to work with the `normden()` function.  Don't know why.

```
outer(x, y, "normden")
```

I get the same error that the OP mentioned, `Error in -tk %*% ss : non-conformable arguments`.